# How do I get a related Model instance by PK from an ORM Model?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy model class `model`, a string denoting an attribute/column `attr` that corresponds to an ORM relationship with another model class *othermodel*, and a private key or `id` string of such an *othermodel*.

I would like to find the object *othermodel*`.get(id)` to store it in a newly constructed instance, using like `setattr(model(), attr, ???)` – but I don't have that *othermodel* accessible in a variable. How do I get that?

I assume I can use some kind of introspection on `model` or its new instance, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through 
`model`'s attributes, I found a copy of *othermodel* in

```
getattr(model, attr).comparator.property.argument
```

turning my assignment into

```
setattr(model(), attr, getattr(model, attr).comparator.property.argument.get(id))
```

Quite a mouthful!
This looks reasonable for the moment, but I am quite sure I am missing a more obvious way to access it.